# is the train moving now? or it is going to go?

Tags: present-continuous

I read the following in a book:

> Excuse me, Is this train going to Granada?

Is the train moving now? or Is it waiting passengers and it is going to go?

Comment: The *present continuous* is a tense that is used for both current actions and  future intended actions. So *I am going to London* can mean either that *it is London to which I'm travelling now* or that *I intend to go to London*. You can only be certain of the meaning if the time (*tomorrow*) or some other clue is added.

Comment: if it is indicate a future event, where is the future word? I'm visiting my friend  tomorrow.  but if I say: I'm visiting my friend without time word. it is mean I'm  visiting my friend now.

Comment: @user178049: While I agree that a future word isn't *always* necessary, I don't think that it has anything to do with English not having a future tense. Suggesting looking up "futurate" does not clarify anything: the future word that Shannak's refers to in his example is  **tomorrow**, and all of the examples in this article https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/futurate do have such a future word.

Comment: @JavaLatte Ohh, I thought the future word Shannak meant was the modal  **will**.

Comment: "Going" in this case doesn't refer at all to movement, it refers only to destination.  "Is this train destined for Granada?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Present continuous](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/present-tense/present-continuous) can be used to talk about something that is happening now, or something that is planned to happen in the future: see the link for other possibilities. The overall context indicates which meaning is intended.

> Excuse me, Is this train going to Granada?

This is something that one person says to another, either whilst on a moving train or whilst on or near a stationary train. Without a context, the sentence is ambiguous- we don't know whether or not the train is moving now. But for those two people it's not ambiguous, because they both know whether or not the train is moving. When you read that sentence in a book, it is ambiguous unless the author gives you additional information that tells you whether or not the train is moving.

Regarding your comment "where is the future word?": the absence of a future word does not mean that it's happening now. The overall context tells you whether it's a current or future event. This could be a future word within the sentence, or it could be a future word in a previous sentence, or it could be implied, or it could be the physical situation.

> I am visiting my friend

If somebody calls you on your phone and asks you where you are, and you give this reply, it is clear to speaker and listener that you are talking about what's happening now. The context is an implied  **now** in the question "where are you?".

If your partner asks what you are planning to do tomorrow and you give this reply, it's clear that you are talking about tomorrow: the context **tomorrow** was specified in a previous sentence.

If your partner is with you and asks whether a planned visit to a friend is going to go ahead, and you give this reply, it's clearly a future event because your partner knows that you are not doing it now: this is physical context.

Answer (score 1):

> Excuse me, is this train going to Granada?

This by itself only classifies the train. It is one (of many trains) that goes from where you are to Granada.
We don't know anything else. It could leave in six hours so no passengers would be waiting, though we have to presume it will eventually go there.

Answer (score -2):

This usage is appropriate for both cases: when the train is already en route, and when the train is not yet moving. The first use is clear; for the second, imagine: Is this train going to Grenada (when it departs)? Just like you can be sitting in your chair, and respond "Yes, I'm going to the store" - even though you are not yet moving.